# Anagram Decoder is Adding Onto Previous String

Tags: c#, string, loops, anagram

so I'm making an Anagram Decoder, and basically, it goes through, picks a unique version of the anagram, and then it adds it to a list and clears it. That way, when it runs through again, if it tries to make that word, it loops back through and tries again. However, when it gets to the end, it adds onto the previous `string`.

By this I mean if the `string` was "hey", the first time it might do "yeh", and the second time it'd do "yehhye". It adds on the new one to the end of the last one. This doesn't make sense though since I clear the variables that would store that (except for the one that stores the before anagrams).

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Anagram_Decoder {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Random random = new Random();
            // Create string, count it, and split it
            string anagram = "hey";
            int anagramLength = anagram.Length;
            int result = anagramLength;

            // Find possibilities
            for (int i = 1; i < anagramLength; i++) {
                result = result * i;
            }

            int anagramPossibilities = result;
            List<string> anagramsFound = new List<string>();
            char[] anagramSplit = anagram.ToCharArray();
            int[] numbers = new int[anagram.Length];
            for (int l = 0; l < anagramPossibilities; l++) {
                string endResult = "";
                bool failed = false;
                while (true) {
                    numbers = new int[anagram.Length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < anagram.Length; i++) {
                        while (true) {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15);
                            int randomNumber = random.Next(1, anagram.Length + 1);
                            foreach (int n in numbers) {
                                if (n == randomNumber && failed == false) {
                                    failed = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (failed == true) {
                                failed = false;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else {
                                numbers[i] = randomNumber;
                                endResult += randomNumber;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    numbers = new int[anagram.Length];
                    failed = false;
                    char[] endResultChars = endResult.ToCharArray();
                    string finalResult = "";
                    foreach (char i in endResultChars) {
                        finalResult += anagram[Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(i)) - 1];
                    }
                    foreach (string n in anagramsFound) {
                        if (n == finalResult && failed == false) {
                            failed = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (failed == true) {
                        failed = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        anagramsFound.Add(finalResult);
                        finalResult = "";
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you inserted break points to monitor what is happening?

Comment: Also you have quite a bit going on in one method.  Troubleshooting problems gets easier if you can break up responsibilities into different methods.  Like `GetRandomCharacter()`.  `while(true)` always gives me a chill.

Comment: Could you, please, provide a *desired outcome*? Let's initialize `Random` as `Random random = new Random(1);` in order to reproduce the results.

Comment: As @FelixCastor said - inserting break points easily showed that you do not clear variable endResult, you need to clear that inside your while(true) loop.